# Moving to a previous statement inside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I have a for loop similar to the one given below.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   boolean condition = checkCondition();    /* line 3 */

   if(condition)
   {
     if(some other condition A)
     {
       move to line 3;
     }
     else if(some other condition B)
     {
      call_method_B();
     }
     else
     {
      call_method_C();
     }
  }
  else
  {
    call_method_D();
  }
}
```

How do I make the program go back to line 3 within the if statement as above? I don't want to break the iteration. Needs to be in the same iteration and only need move back to line 3.

Comment: You'll need a loop.

Comment: I believe, Instead of using iteration, you can prefer recursive approach if you have some base condition

Comment: Yes I understand I need a recursive approach. I can't use a loop as shmosel suggested since the functionality I require is recursive. But I cannot figure out exactly how to do it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @zim : I've posted an answer using recursive approach. You can reference from that approach.

Comment: Can you use break / goto labels?

Comment: What that 10 signifies in the first loop? If you want to go to line 3 and increment the count, inside if for condition A, use 

    continue;

Comment: @cricket_007 : I am not sure whether it's good practice to use `goto` label in java as I've little knowledge of java

Comment: While its perfectly Okay to use recursive solution, a better approach would be to use either Thread or design patterns like Event Listener / Callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem seems to need a recursive approach instead of an iterative approach.

The above problem can be solved using a recursive approach in the following way:

```
public void checkRecursive()
{
    boolean condition = checkCondition(); 

    if (base_condition_to_avoid_recursion)
        return;

    if (condition)
    {
        if (some other condition A)
        {
            checkRecursive();
        }
        else if (some other condition B)
        {
            call_method_B();
        }
        else
        {
            call_method_C();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        call_method_D();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for directing me towards a recursive approach. This works best with my problem. I'm accepting this answer as it is the best approach with my actual code which is more complicated and having a separate recursive method helps for other parts of the code as well.

Answer (score 2):

to be in the same iteration, just subtract i by 1 before you call continue.
do note that this will get you into an infinite loop if the condition is never changed.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   boolean condition = checkCondition();    /* line 3 */

   if(condition)
   {
     if(some other condition A)
     {
       move to line 3;
       i--;  //this will cancel out the i++ in the for loop  
       continue; //this will bring you back to line 3
     }

     ... the rest of your codes
```

Comment: I think this is the correct solution.... You could also move the `int i = 0` out, use `while (i < 10)`, then put `i++` where it needs to be incremented

Comment: I believe this is the best approach with a simple code as I have mentioned and thank you :) So +1 for your answer. But for my problem a recursive approach was much useful.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to break the iteration. Needs to be in the same iteration and only need move back to line 3.

I think you need a while loop. Then you have more control over when you iterate. When you get the conditionA check, then `i` doesn't change, and the loop repeats, otherwise you can say `i++`.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    if (checkCondition()) {
        if (some other condition A) {
            // continue the iteration
        } else if (some other condition B) {
            call_method_B();
            i++;
        } else {
            call_method_C();
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        call_method_D();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. +1 for your answer. A recursive approach was much helpful with my particular problem but yours also solves the problem I had. :)